# How to get an array of multi checkbox on ionic4?

Tags: checkbox, ionic4, ion-checkbox

I'm trying to get an array with a multi checkbox on ionic 4, can someone help me?

```js
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">0</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox  color="primary" value="0"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">1</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox color="secondary" value="1"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">2</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox color="danger" value="2"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-label position="floating">3</ion-label>
          <ion-checkbox color="light" value="3"></ion-checkbox>
        </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to get an array from your .ts file to your html dynamically and load the content into the ion-items? Set a global variable into your .ts file. Lets call it `data`.

Then your html should look like this:
 home.html:

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let data-object of data">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label position="floating">{{data-object.value}}</ion-label>
      <ion-checkbox color="secondary" value="{{data-object.value}}"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Where data is your array with data objects.

Comment: HI, Eve. could you please explain more on how to select multiple checkbox values and store that in JSON object. like user selected values stored in JSON { A,B,C,E}